# How to make wordpress post listing page in Twig/Timber?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, twig, timber

I'm using Timber in my WordPress theme. I created route for my /blog page which should contain posts list.

```
Routes::map('blog', function($params) {
    Routes::load('loop.php', $params, false, 200);
});
```

In my `loop.php` file I have this code

```
$context = Timber::get_context();
$args = ['posts_per_page' => 5, 'post_type' => 'post'];
$context['post'] = Timber::get_posts( $args );
$post = new TimberPost();
$context['post'] = $post;

Timber::render( 'loop/post-loop.twig', $context );
```

next in post-loop.twig

```
{% if posts %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        {{ post.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No matching posts</p>
{% endif %}
```

And now, `{{post.title}}` don't display actual post title but whole page title which is "blog". Even if there's no posts loop print data. My question is what is wrong with my code and how can I make page which contain list of my posts. But in proper way.

Comment: You variable is `post` not `posts`, see `$context['post']`

Comment: @DarkBee even if I change my if statement to post and my for to "for item in post" it doesn't work. Loop doesn't work

Comment: `{{ dump(posts) }}`?

Comment: @DarkBee it return me actual blog page. But, I think we're almost there. When I comment $post = new TimberPost(); and $context['post'] = $post; the loop starts working. But, I need to print page title. {{ page.title }} don't work. Question is, how to keep new TimberPost() with Timber::get_posts()?